# Symfony2 StreamedResponse won't allow me to loop or set variables

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to set up a StreamedResponse so I can export a csv file. But I can't get anything other than static arrays to go into the stream.

This function does not work

```
public function exampleCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $tests = array(
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three')
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');

        // THIS LOOP BREAKS THE RESPONSE
        foreach ($tests as $test) {
            fputcsv($handle, $test, ',');
        }

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.csv"');
    return $response;
}
```

But if I get rid of the foreach loop it does work

```
public function exampleCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $tests = array(
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three')
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.csv"');
    return $response;
}
```

calling the count() function also breaks it

```
public function exampleCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $tests = array(
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three')
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');

        // THIS COUNT BREAKS THE RESPONSE
        $i = count($tests);

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.csv"');
    return $response;
}
```

EDIT:

If I try to fputcsv one of the $tests "rows" it also breaks

```
public function exampleCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $tests = array(
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three')
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');

        // THIS FPUTCSV BREAKS THE RESPONSE
        fputcsv($handle, $test[0], ',');

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.csv"');
    return $response;
}
```

But I can put the fputcsv multiple time if the array is inline

```
public function exampleCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $tests = array(
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three')
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.csv"');
    return $response;
}
```

In the cases where it doesn't work, chrome is redirected to the route for my action and displays a "ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE" message

How can I use the StreamedResponse to do something useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what I missed here, I forgot to use() the variables outside the callback function

```
public function exampleCsvAction(Request $request)
{
    $tests = array(
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        array('one', 'two', 'three')
    );

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () use(&$tests) {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
        fputcsv( $handle, array('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'), ',');

        foreach ($tests as $test) {
            fputcsv($handle, $test, ',');
        }

        fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.csv"');
    return $response;
}
```